# Popup form changing textbox value only once

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an asp page which calling another popup page on button click event. and few values are returned from the popup page by following code.

```
       function ShowSelfpopup() {var customizeParamGL = 'status:no;help:no;dialogWidth:600px;dialogHeight:550px;scrolling=no';

        var FunctionID = document.getElementById("ctl00_contPlcHdrMasterHolder_LstxtHidFUNCTION_ID").value;
        window.showModalDialog('corBrmBlockIssuAndMaintFindUI.aspx?Function_Id=' + FunctionID + '', window, customizeParamGL);
        debugger;
        if (XYZ_PID != '') {
            debugger;
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contPlcHdrMasterHolder_LsddlProductID99").value = XYZ_PID;
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contPlcHdrMasterHolder_LstxtStartNo").value = XYZ_SN;
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contPlcHdrMasterHolder_LstxtEndNo").value = XYZ_EN;
            document.getElementById("ctl00_contPlcHdrMasterHolder_lstxthide").value = XYZ_BP;

            aspnetForm.submit();
            return true;

        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Now I have a Text changed event method for LstxtEndNo. Which is firing only first time I am getting data from the popup form. next time I'm calling the popup form and getting data as i confirmed by debugging. but its neither changing values in the textbox nor firing text changed event.

Comment: have you checked for script errors ? btw you should be using `.ClientId`. parent control ids might change

Comment: Is `XYZ_PID` never blank after the first time?  `if (XYZ_PID != '') {`

Comment: I have debugged the script. There is no error and everytime it return correct values.
i guess some how document.getElementById is not working after first time. dont know why. where same code is working fine in some other pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot. in the text changed event i haved changed the readonly property true. Thats why its not firing from 2nd time.

Comment: Please stop using `showModalDialog` ASAP. Chrome dropped support for it already, Firefox soon to follow.

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript Dont use Textchange event instead onchange

```
<head runat="server">
<title>

</title>
   <script>
       function AlertTest()
       {
           alert('hELLO');
       }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">           </ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>

            <asp:TextBox ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onchange="AlertTest()" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Try this with your example